# Fluid mechanics on force exerted

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics

Fluids obey the Bernoulli equation :a fluid will move from a high pressure area to a low pressure area. If we have a box with a pressure of 2 atm and we open it air will flow from the box to the atmosphere.

And due to conservation of momentum the box will start travelling to the opposite direction of the flow of air.

Using the Bernoulli equation we can calculate the speed of the air coming out of the box but it doesn't say anything about the force exerted on the box. How can I find that?

Comment: What is the problem? You know how the momentum of the box is changing so just take the derivative to get the force

Comment: How can I know that?

Comment: you said yourself the Bernoulli equation gives you speed of the air coming out, from this you get momentum of the air coming out and this gives you momentum of the box (due to conservation of momentum). Thus you know momentum of the box.

Comment: I get kinetic energy/volume not momentum.

Comment: kinetic energy is just $E_k=\frac{p^2}{2m}=\frac{p^2}{2\rho V},$ so $\frac{p^2}{V^2}=2\frac{E_k}{V}\rho$

Comment: The speed of the air coming out is changing.